# Libname with libref: how to access to a data source (library)

Tags: sas

I need to access a dataset into a library (/data/....) and create a temporary dataset/table to not overwrite the original one.

What I tried is to use the libname with libref:

`libname libref '/data/....';`

and create a temporary file using a data step:

```
     set original;
run;
```

But something does not work, because I have not access to the folder dataset. Do I need to specify something else to the libname?
The path that I have is /data/folder/, without any information about the directory (example C:). Should I specify it?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
libname mylib "/data/...";

data copy;
  set mylib.original;
run;
```